# NestJS Middleware Not Executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, fastify

The NestJS class or functional middleware doesn't run when connected from a Module. It is also not working for a single path, controller or for every path. Connecting functional middleware from main.ts works fine.

```
//main.ts
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common'
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core'
import { FastifyAdapter, NestFastifyApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify'
import { AppModule } from './app.module'

declare const module: any

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(AppModule, new FastifyAdapter())

  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe())

  await app.listen(2100)

  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept()
    module.hot.dispose(() => app.close())
  }
}
bootstrap()
```

```
//app.module.ts
import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module, NestModule } from '@nestjs/common'
import { AuthMiddleware } from './middleware/auth.middleware'
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module'

@Module({
  imports: [UserModule],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(AuthMiddleware)
      .forRoutes('(.*)')
  }
}
```

```
//auth.middleware.ts
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common'
import { FastifyRequest, FastifyReply } from 'fastify'

@Injectable()
export class AuthMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: FastifyRequest, res: FastifyReply, next: () => void) {
    console.log('test auth middleware')
    next()
  }
}
```

Expected output: test auth middleware 
Actual: nothing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was installing the "fastify" package along with "@nestjs/platform-fastify". In addition, if you remove the "fastify" package, then the dependencies used in the "@nestjs/platform-fastify" package are also removed, so it won't work correctly. If you've installed both packages, uninstall "fastify" and reinstall "@nestjs/platform-fastify".

Comment: I agree, had the same problem and after that, it works.

Comment: I found that ensuring you install the same fastify version as what @nestjs/platform-fastify uses also fixes the problem.

Comment: Your are right, it's working for me with same solution, Thanks you

Comment: Not sure i've understand what should my package.json looks like? just @nestjs/platform-fastify

Comment: @BallonUra If you have installed both packages @nestjs/platform-fastify and fastify, then uninstall both with "npm uninstall" and then install just  @nestjs/platform-fastify

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is:
I defined the route earlier like below with a `/` at the end of the route.

```
@Controller('v1/partnerPortal/')
export class SubscriptionController {
  constructor()
}
```

I remove the slash and it is now working for me

```
@Controller('v1/partnerPortal')
export class SubscriptionController {
  constructor()
}
```

My module code:

```
export class SubscriptionModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void {
    consumer.apply(KeyAuthMiddlewareService).forRoutes(SubscriptionController);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! adding a slash at end of the route / path worked

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Fastify but my middleware wasnt executing even taken straight from the docs. I built my project (`npm run build`) then went back to dev mode `npm run start:dev` and that seemed to work. When in doubt investigate the `/dist` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Works just fine when using an explicit controller, but not with '*'.
Also tried:

```
forRoutes({path: '*', method: RequestMethod.ALL })
```

but that doesn't seem to work either.
My solution was, unfortunately, using a global functional middleware, as the example [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware#functional-middleware) shows.
This is not not very maintainable, since it is defined in main.ts and not in app.module.
This caused some problems with e2e testing, but I was able to make it work, eventually. Just make sure to use the middleware in main.ts and when creating a test module for e2e tests.

main.ts:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
app.use(functionalMiddleware);
```

in your e2e test module:

```
const createAppE2e = async (): Promise<INestApplication> => {
   const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
     imports: [AppModule],
   });
   const app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
   app.use(functionalMiddleware);
   await app.init();
   return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to apply one middleware globally, and one middleware at a specific module level.
But For some reason, middleware doesn't work when you apply it at a specific module level.

```
export class PartnerModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(ModuleSpecificMiddleware);
  }
}
```

So I found another way to do it. At app module you can assign it like this.

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(AuthMiddleware);
    consumer.apply(ModuleSpecificMiddleware).forRoutes(PartnerController); // This was the solution
  }
}
```